# In Android how to set the layerlist

Tags: android

In Android I want Below pic type of layout..Here is my code:--

### "bg_select.xml"

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:bottom="20dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <size android:height="20dp" />
            <solid android:color="#969595" />
            <corners
                android:radius = "0dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
                android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="30dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <size android:height="20dp" />
            <solid android:color="‪#‎7B7979‬" />
            <corners
                android:radius = "0dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:topRightRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and my layout code is:--

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="‪#‎F3F3F3‬">
</LinearLayout>
```

But I am not getting the exact page.. first pic is [**What I want**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOORv.png) And second pic is [**what I am getting**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omX3z.png)..can anyone help me to achieve that exact page???  Here color code is changed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also add `android:bottomLeftRadius` and `android:bottomRightRadius` attributes in `android:bottom` item.

Change :

```
        <corners
            android:radius="0dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
            android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
```

to

```
        <corners
            android:radius="0dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
            android:topRightRadius="20dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"/>
```

Comment: @Ghostrider: i have also tried and working fine so use in same way as in answer

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K,Thanks boss...Its working when I run..But It was not showing in the graphical view of android-studio/ in eclipse..

Comment: @Ghostrider: yes probably due to same Api  related issue

Comment: How Can I correct it??If I want to see the above views in graphical view of android-studio/eclipse..what I have to do???

Comment: @Ghostrider: try it after changing api level of project to lower

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
<corners
android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
android:topRightRadius="20dp"
android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
android:bottomRightRadius="20dp" />
```

you can simply use:

```
<corners android:radius="20dp"/>
```

its cleaner.